# I want to call a function of class in another function but I tried all way around still have errors

Tags: python

```
class Employee:    

    'Common base class for all employees'
    empCount = 0
    def __init__(self, name, salary):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary
        Employee.empCount += 1
    def displayCount(self):
        print "Total Employee %d" % Employee.empCount
    def displayEmployee(self):
        print "Name : ", self.name,
        ", Salary: ", self.salary
        self.displaycount()


emp1 = Employee("Zara", 2000)

emp1.displayEmployee()
```

Comment: Which error exactly are you getting?

Comment: Maybe the call `self.displaycount()` should be `self.displayCount()`

Comment: If the error you were  seeing is `AttributeError: Employee instance has no attribute 'displaycount'`, then apply the edit @Quallenmann suggested. If that is not the error you are getting, please provide the traceback

Comment: Side note: the first line should be `class Employee(object):` unless you have a good reason this needs to be an old-style class instead of a modern one.

Comment: Also, `displayCount` probably should be a `@staticmethod`, because it's only accessing attributes of the class, not of the instance (or any subclass). Also, instead of having `displayFoo` methods that format a string and `print` it, you might find it more useful to have methods that format a string and `return` it.

Comment: As a rule, you will attract fewer downvotes if you are more specific than *"have errors"*. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

```
print "Name : ", self.name,
", Salary: ", self.salary
self.displaycount()
```

is interpreted as three logical lines:

```
print "Name : ", self.name,  # print two things, suppress the newline
", Salary: ", self.salary  # this makes no sense - tuple? Gets ignored
self.displaycount()  # call a method - but Python is case sensitive!
```

Python doesn't implicitly continue logical lines. You could add a backslash for explicit continuation:

```
print "Name : ", self.name, \
", Salary: ", self.salary
```

but I think it would be much better to use proper [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
print "Name: {0.name}, Salary: {0.salary:.02f}".format(self)
```

You also need to *use the correct case* for accessing methods (Python is *case-sensitive*), so it should then be:

```
self.displayCount()
          # ^ note
```

Alternatively, per [the style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), name it `display_count`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help, it solved with implementing your tips. thanks so much

Comment: He could also use parentheses for continuation… although that's awkward with `print` unless from `from __future__ import print_function`, and you already gave the even better solution of using string formatting, so… I don't think that needs to go in the answer…

Comment: @abarnert I did think of that, you just end up printing a tuple (unless, as you say, you go 3.x-style).

Comment: @jonrsharpe: There are awkward ways around the tuple-printing. Consider `print 1, (\n    2), (\n    3)`. Of course that isn't PEP8 compliant, but you can make it technically compliant (and good enough to pass `pep8`) by adding a bunch of extra whitespace and making it even uglier if you really want to. :)

Comment: @abarnert so many revolting options!

Comment: @jonrsharpe: If we ever need to revise the Zen, I think that has to go in there. "There should be one— and preferably only one —obvious way to do it. But then unobvious ways, sure, as many as you want, and as revolting as you want. So many revolting options!"

Comment: @abarnert I would support that PEP ;o)